# Binder.GetMember Method not intended to use? why?

Tags: c#, dynamic, msdn

In the documentation of [`Binder.GetMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.runtimebinder.binder.getmember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), Microsoft just mentioned that

> This API supports the product infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.

Why they mention it for this API. Is there any possible failure scenario  for this API. If I use it in my implementation is that misleading in someway?

Comment: Weren't Microsoft forced to document APIs as part of the DoJ antitrust settlement?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the method has to be `public` for some reason (they use it in a package that can't be marked as friend assembly, else the method could have marked `internal`), and they don't want to pin themselves to this method with this signature.

It is possible that this method doesn't exist any more in the next version or that its signature changes. They won't keep this method or create migration paths. You can use it, and it probably works, but without any guarantees.